# Not allow two or more zero's regex at the start for custom angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

I'm writing an angular directive which only allows user to enter numbers in input field within range.

**html code**

```
<input non-negative-number range-min="1" range-max="5000" ng-model="number1">
     <input non-negative-number range-min="0" range-max="1000" ng-model="number2">
```

**angular directive**

```
angular.module("NumberDirective", [])
   .directive('nonNegativeNumber', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var lastVal = null;
            if (!ngModel) { return; }

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {

                lastVal = ngModel.$modelValue;
                var pattern = /[^0-9]+/g;
                var parsed = val.replace(pattern, '');
                if (parseInt(parsed) > parseInt(attrs.rangeMax)) { parsed = lastVal; }
                if (parseInt(parsed) < parseInt(attrs.rangeMin)) { parsed = lastVal; }
                if (val !== parsed) {
                    lastVal = parsed;
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(parsed);
                    ngModel.$render();
                }
                return parsed;
            });

            element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
                if(event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
   });
```

This is working fine but I also need to have regex which must not allow typing two zero's at the start of the input,

like 00 , 0000000000045, 00000000000000000000000100

can anyone suggest the correct regex ??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^[0]{0,1}[1-9]\d{0,}

^ asserts position at start of the string
Match a single character present in the list below [0]{0,1}
{0,1} Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
0 matches the character 0 literally (case sensitive)

Match a single character present in the list below [1-9]
1-9 a single character in the range between 1 (ASCII 49) and 9 (ASCII 57) (case sensitive)

\d{0,} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
{0,} Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using like this 
var pattern = /^[0]{0,1}[1-9]\d+/;
but it's still allowing as many 0's as i want which is wrong in my case

Comment: You want to allow one zero and no more than one. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I want user should only be able to type one zero at the start of the number like 01, 02 etc but  not 001, 00000001.
valid input: 
1, 01, 099, 99 etc
invalid input:
001, 0001, 000099 etc etc

Comment: Have revised the regex. Check out.

Comment: not working
i found the following one useful 
/[^0-9]+/g
there is one issue with this, as it allows as many zeros at the start of input which is wrong, ideally i would like something which can allow one zero at start or but no more zero at start
valid input should be
0,1, 01,099,100,10000000
invalid input
00,001,00100,00100000

Comment: I have tested the expression above. As you can see in the explanation of expression, it allows only only one `0`. Could you test again.

Comment: i'm sorry if i was not clear but i'm trying to write regex expression which if find invalid character then replace that invalid character with  empty string ('').In my case the characters should be valid if they are only positive numbers and they dont start with two or more zeros.
var pattern = /^[0]{0,1}[1-9]\d{0,}/;  var parsed = val.replace(pattern, '');
Note: val is an input like abcdgj, 0010000, 0001111198 etc etc
But using above mentioned expression it allows to enter any other  characters as well like alphabets, special characters, negative numbers etc which is wrong in my scenario.